# errors in the program

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is a copied program and thought i would get the output. But damn its not even compiling. can anyone correct these errors and explain why 6 errors on the same line?
if there are any websites i can learn java through example codes, ill be glad to know that.
(beginner)
Thanks in advance

```
import java.*;
import java.util.*;
class beer{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int beernum=99;
        String word="bottles";
        while(beernum > 0)
        {
            if (beernum==1)
            {
                word="bottle";
            }

            System.out.println(beernum+""+word+"of beer on wall");
            System.out.println(beernum+""+word+"of beer");
            System.out.println("take one down.");
            System.out.println("pass it around");
            beernum=beernum-1;

            if(beernum>0)
            {
                System.out.println(beernum+""+word+"of beer on wall");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("no more bottles on the wall");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Errors which im getting

```
C:\mywork>javac beer.java
beer.java:4: error: <identifier> expected
  public Static void main(String[] args)
               ^
beer.java:4: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
  public Static void main(String[] args)
                     ^
beer.java:44: error: class, interface, or enum expected
beer.java:4: error: <identifier> expected
^
beer.java:45: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  public Static void main(String[] args)
         ^
beer.java:47: error: class, interface, or enum expected
beer.java:4: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
                                                ^
beer.java:48: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  public Static void main(String[] args)
         ^
6 errors
```

Comment: `Static` must be lowercase, otherwise it won't work. Make it:`public static void main(....)`

Comment: Also, please pick a summary for your question that explains the problem, not your feelings.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Programming-Java-For-Dummies/dp/0470371749

Comment: silly silly silly i dint check that.
thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
public Static void main(String[] args) //'S' in static must be replaced by 's'
```

`Java` is a case sensitive language, and each `keyword` must be written in **lower case letters**, As `static` is a keyword too,you must use lower case letters for it.
and

---

Also name of the class is `beer`; although there is no error because of it,but you must follow some coding conventions and rename it as `Beer`.

---

- For learning about other **coding conventions** visit here
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html
- And here is the list of **java keywords** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually `Static` is what you got wrong here because if it starts with a capital letter it means it's a class.

Here, you want the key word for a static method so it has to be in lower case : `static`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```